# find function printing everything?

Tags: c++, find

```
                    if((tempTitle.find(tempTitleFind)))
                    {
                      blah blah

                    }
```

when I have a partial match, everything is printed instead of just the one with the partial match, do I have an argument wrong here?? I have looked over it again and again and seems like I cant find one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might find some use in a little trick: `std::transform` is an easy way to convert a string to lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if it isn't found, and that's equal to -1. Anything not 0 is equivalent to a boolean `true`, so you get "false positives". Change the condition to:

```
if(tempTitle.find(tempTitleFind) != std::string::npos)
```

Answer (score 0):

tempTitle.find(tempTitleFind) returns the position of tempTitleFind within tempTitle, or std::string::npos if tempTitleFind doesn't occur in tempTitle.

To determine whether tempTitleFind occurs within tempTitle, you can use the following snippet:

```
if(tempTitle.find(tempTitleFind)!=std::string::npos)
{
...
}
```

BTW: you should convert titleFind to lower case *before* the loop, not within.